# Laravel 404 JSON response returning different message in HTTP & HTTPS

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, https

In my `routes/api.php` I have a **POST** method route as such:

```php
Route::post('hello', 'MyController@greet');
```

In the `app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php` the `greet()` method is defined as such:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function greet(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['not found'], 404);
    }
}
```

Now, depending on the URL protocol that was calling from, the response is returning totally different messages:

Calling from POST **https**://localhost/hello will return **404** Not Found response:

```
[
    "not found"
]
```

as expected.

Wheres, when calling from POST **http**://localhost/hello (without http**s**) it will return **405** Method Not Allowed response instead:

```
{
    "message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."
}
```

This is a problem because I'm setting up my server behind AWS ELB which accepts HTTPS traffic only but will route back to the Auto Scaling instances via HTTP within the local VPC network.

So my question is what is causing this and how can I prevent Laravel from returning a different response based on URL protocol?

EDIT: Note that this only happens when I specify the *status code* in the `response()->json($data, [status code])`. Otherwise, the response works normally as expected.

Comment: Do you have a redirect set up to send http -> https? If so, that will lose the method and change it to GET.

Comment: No, I don't. I didn't know that method will get changed to GET when https is routed to http in ELB. But, even when I'm testing from localhost environment without any ELB, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

None of those has to work, because you have defined your route as a post. Your requests are 'get' requests. It seems there is middleware in a higher priority and it's being called when it's an HTTP request to control illegal requests.

Try returning different things like dd("Hello World"); if it's loading the page there has to be a bug or something.

Temporarily add a middleware to your route to redirect requests to one of HTTP or HTTPS protocols

Comment: FYI the requests being sent are **POST** requests. The middleware in question would be the **TrustProxies** which is explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies I will try your troubleshooting suggestion.

Comment: So the problem is simple then. You're not making a post request; The error is straight-forward "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.". Change Route::post('hello', 'MyController@greet'); to Route::get('hello', 'MyController@greet'); I think it will be solved, make requests by your browser

Comment: To be clear I need the route to be a **POST** method because I'm also sending a POST body data in the requests made.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

It turns out that I was using the nginx configuration from https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#server-configuration and included the following line:

```
error_page 404 /index.php;
```

This causes all 404 responses to redirect to the `/index.php` page, which is not defined in my Laravel routes, and the path expects a GET instead of POST method. Hence, it returns the error message stated in my question above.

After removing the above config line in my nginx configuration, my POST requests with 404 responses are working correctly again.

Thanks for all the help anyway.